# Thread safety of class level new delete operators in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have re-implemented the new/delete operators in one of my classes. Now I am making my code multi-threaded and would like to understand if these operators need to be made thread safe as well. I have read somewhere that the default new/delete operators in Visual Studio are threadsafe. But does it hold true for custom new/delete operators of my classes?

```
void* MyClass::operator new(std::size_t count)
{
    void* memo = ::operator new(count);
    printf("Allocated base\n");
    return memo;
}
```

Comment: It depends on your `new`/`delete` implementation. If you are just calling standard operators like in your example, its already thread safe. If you create your own memory manager, you have to ensure that it would work correctly in the multithreaded environment.

Comment: For Unix, one must always consider [this](http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/threads-and-fork-think-twice-before-using-them) issue with forking and threading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your own `new` operator must be thread safe if it is used with multiple execution threads.

If your own `new` operator only calls other thread-safe functions, and does not do anything that introduces an execution concurrency conflict, then there's nothing to be done, your `new` operator is thread-safe by default.

So, for your operator, you will need to analyze every function call, and every line of its code to determine whether there's a concurrency issue that must be explicitly addressed. Which is really no different than writing anything else that must work correctly with multiple execution threads, so the `new` operator does not really introduce any special requirements of its own when it comes to thread safety, just because it is the `new` operator.